# Is there a way to deploy machine learning models on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I have created machine learning regression models locally that take a row of a data frame as input and provide a single (or two) numbers as output using sk-learn in Python. I was wondering if it was possible for me to take in the inputs of a few rows in Google Sheets as input and then provide as output the result of model.predict(row_input) if the model is somewhere running in a cloud functions that gets triggered when all the rows are filled (maybe I can look into cloud scheduler for this)?

But how would I deploy (or connect) the machine learning model to Google Sheets in the first place? I haven't come across much resources on the internet about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is in Python, I recommend you to deploy it on [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs) and to write a script, to define your [own Google Sheet function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), and use it to call your Google Cloud Functions.

**EDIT**

You have 2 ways to implement it

---

Firstly, you can deploy your code on a Cloud Functions and call it with the params that you want (an array of value contained in the row for example). You receive the answer that you put into the cell

---

Secondly, you can also deploy your code in a Cloud Function and call it only with some references, I mean:

- The file ID
- The row range (A1-A10)
- The target cell to write the result

Then, the Cloud Functions opens the file, get the result and write directly the result in the sheet.

---

The second solution is asynchronous and imply that the Cloud Functions identity (the service account of the Cloud Function) is authorized to read and write on the file.

The first solution is synchronous and can be applied on any sheet or other applications.

Why I presented both? Because of the security. If you don't want to open your Cloud Function to anybody (and to pay for nothing the processing), you have to secure the access to your Cloud Function

---

For the first solution, you have to be authenticated, but it doesn't work with the user authentication, you need an identity token signed by Google with the correct audience. Thus you need to have a service account. But that means that you need to generate a service account key file and to store it in your script. Not a very secure place, but you can.

---

For the second solution, it's the same thing. Except that you are in asynchronous mode and you can use a trick: PubSub. Indeed, you can use an the user access token to publish a message into PubSub, and to plug securely your Cloud Function on PubSub. the processing is done near real time by the Cloud Function which update by its own the sheet. However, you have to grand the access to the sheet at the Cloud Functions identity, and you can't apply this solution for any sheets.

---

I hope it's clear. If not, don't hesitate to ask me more.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! So is the suggestion to write a google cloud function that contains all the machine learning code to call model.predict() for an archived model and then use Google Sheet function (which seems to be in Javascript) to call. the cloud function and. pass the row as input parameters?

Comment: I appreciate the added comments! I ended up creating a cloud function that I called using Google Apps Script